# How to browse file systems in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to be able to browse file systems from within Eclipse 3.6.2. As I understand it this is supposed to be possible with Remote Systems Explorer, but when I open the Remote Systems view it is empty. How can I make it show my file system? Or is there an alternative way to browse files from inside Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new folder using File -> New -> Folder

Expand the "Advanced" options at the bottom of the dialog. Select the last option ("Linked folder") to "link/map" a certain folder of your hard disk into your project.

This is like a soft link: It makes the files and folders from your hard disk visible under the new project folder. The data isn't copied and not accessible to, say, unit test code.

Example: You link `C:\` or `/` to `hd`. This test would then pass:

```
assertFalse( new File( "hd" ).exists() );
```

but you could browse your whole hard disk from the Project and Package Explorer views.

**[EDIT]** The question is really how to access remote files (probably mapped by NFS or a network share or the like) with Eclipse.

There is no satisfactory way to do that. Network drives have features that make them problematic:

1. Network lag and outages.
2. Locking
3. Notification of changes

The first problem makes Eclipse slow (if you have a lag) or it can even hang the UI while Eclipse is waiting for a file API to return.

Then someone might have a file locked (or locking doesn't work reliably which is worse in a different way).

Lastly, Eclipse wants to make sure that files in your workspace are "current". To do that, it has strategies that work well (more or less) on a local hard disk but depending on your file server OS and bugs, this can cause all kinds of trouble.

The usual solution is to move the files to a version control system. That way, each developer can have their own copy and all the problems above can be avoided.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this would require that I already have a project in my workspace?

Comment: Yes. You can create a "generic project" so you won't have to bother with warnings from the Java compiler. Or you can add them to an existing project.

Comment: Creating the folder seems to take forever. Perhaps this works well for smaller file systems but I'm working in  shared hub environment and since I want something that works for different users of a shared Eclipse installation I do not think I can use your solution.

Comment: That's odd. Creating the link shouldn't take any time at all. Are you sure the folder is on your local hard disk? If you access network shares this way, network problems can ruin your day.

Comment: It's not on my local hard disk, it's a shared environment.

Comment: Then your question has the wrong title. "local file" is on your local hard disk. You want to access remote files.

Comment: You're right of course, I've changed it now. I actually wanted a solution that would work for both, so I didn't think to make a difference between the two. I've noticed that I can use your approach as long as I link to lower level directories, so that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the remote system explorer. Over time I got used to a workaround for that. if you are intending to browse the same location in your FS, create a new vanilla project rooted in the folder you would like to inspect.

We are using this workaround to keep the application server in sight.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the file system (the root at least) is read only, unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: This seems very probable as eclipse usually insists on creating a `.project` file in the project root folder. I wasn't aware of the read-only requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the corresponding Eclipse resource in the Windows Explorer/Mac Finder then you can use the following Eclipse plug-in.

https://code.google.com/p/show-file-on-disk/